# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'app' available as request attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

i am getting this eror in my spring mvc 3.2 + jdbc project.

"HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'app' available as request attribute"

i have seen my people asked this question. i have gone through the answers . but nbothing s working for me. please help me . thanks in advance.

**This is my HomeController.java:-**

```
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
            import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
            import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
            import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
            import MediatoPrima.Beans.Application;
            import MediatoPrima.services.ApplicationService;  
            import java.util.HashMap;   
            import java.util.List;   
            import java.util.Map;      

            @Controller  
            public class MediatoPrimaController {

                @Autowired  
                ApplicationService applicationService;   

                @RequestMapping("/AppMgt_AddnewApp")
                 public ModelAndView registerUser(@ModelAttribute("application") Application app) {

                  List<String> LobList = new ArrayList<String>();
                  LobList.add("Asia");
                  LobList.add("Australia");
                  LobList.add("America");
                  LobList.add("Europe");

                  Map<String, List> map = new HashMap<String, List>();
                  map.put("cityList", LobList);
                  return new ModelAndView("AppMgt_AddnewApp", "map", map);
                 }

                @RequestMapping("/insert") 
                public String inserData(@ModelAttribute Application application) {   
                    if (application != null)   
                        applicationService.addnewApp(application);   
                    return "redirect:/AppManagment";   
                }   

            }
```

***this is my ApMgt_AddnewApp.jsp***
this is the welcome file of the prijct

```
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
            pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

        <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
        <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
        <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="css/Appmang.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>:: New Application < title>
           </head>
        <body>
        <div id="content_page_for_userHome"><br>
              <div id="divForSideNavigation">
        <center>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="AppMgt_AddnewApp.html"><img src="Images/add.png"
                border="0" /><br>
            New Application</a></li>
        </ul>
        </center>
        </div>


        <div id="addnewBox_app"><form:form action="AddnewApp"
            method="post" modelAttribute="application">
            <center><c:url var="action" value="/AppMgt_AddnewApp.html"></c:url>
          <form:form method="post" action="/insert" modelAttribute="app">  

                <table>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <td>APPID</td>

                        <td><form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8"  disabled="true" id="txt"/>
                    <form:hidden path="id" /></td>
                        <td>*</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr align="left">
                        <td>APPCODE</td>
                        <td><form:input path="AppCode" /></td>
                        <td>*</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr align="left">
                        <td>APPLICATION</td>
                        <td><form:input path="Appname" /></td>
                        <td>*</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <td>LOB</td>
                        <td><form:input path="lob" /></td>
                        <td>*</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <td>geog</td>
                        <td><form:input path="geo" /></td>
                        <td>*</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <td>DESC</td>
                        <td><form:input path="desc" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="left">
                        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save" class="Appbutton"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button"
                            value="Cancel" class="Appbutton" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form:form></center>
        </form:form></div>

        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

***this is my spring-servlet.xml file***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd   
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

        <!-- telling container to take care of annotations stuff -->
        <context:annotation-config />

        <!-- declaring base package -->
        <context:component-scan base-package="com" />

        <!-- adding view resolver to show jsp's on browser -->
        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </bean>

        <!-- declare beans -->
        <bean id="ApplicationDao" class="com.Dao.ApplicationDaoImpl" />
        <bean id="ApplicationService"
            class="com.services.ApplicationServiceImpl" />

        <!-- declare datasource bean -->
        <bean id="dataSource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.21.51.32:1521:sid" />
            <property name="username" value="uname" />
            <property name="password" value="pwd" />
        </bean>
    </beans>



this is my web.xml file


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
 id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <display-name>SpringJDBCTemplate</display-name>
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>AppMgt_AddnewApp.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>



and these are the jars am using.
![These are the jars am using.][1]
```

[image: these are the jars am using]

Comment: why do you have form in form?

Comment: that was by mistake, i removed the outer form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is, in jsp it should be `modelAttribute="application"`:

```
<form:form method="post" action="/insert" modelAttribute="application">
```

PS: you'd better add `method="POST"` in `@RequestMapping`

Comment: @Msn then for workaround, add `BindingResult result` to the prameter list